# Publishing Content Types through Content Type Hub in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, term-store, content-type-hub

I've been fighting with this for 2 days now and still won't get any content types published from content type hubs.

To cut the long story short, here's what I've done so far (in addition to drinking 2 pans of coffee, smoking a pack of cigaretter, having absolutely no life and sleeping on the sofa):

**Note:** Probably worth mentionin I've done this in InPrivate IE11 (there was some things bugged (can't remember what) that required this.

**SPO Admin Center**

1. Added myself into `Term Store Administrators` in `SPO Admin Center`
2. Added a new `Term Group`
3. Added a new `Term Set`

**Content Type Hub**

1. Went to `Content Type Hub` at https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contentTypeHub/
2. Added myself as the `Site collection administrator`
3. Created a new `Content Type` in `Site Settings` > `Site Content Types`
4. Added a new `Site Column` into the new `Content Type` which points to the previously created `Term Set` in `Managed Metadata`
5. Went to `Site Settings`  > `Site Content Types` > (content type just created) > `Manage publishing for this content type` > `Publish` > `OK`

**Document Center**

1. Went to a `Document Center` at https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/production/
2. Added a new `Document Library`
3. Went to `Library` > `Library Settings` > `Advanced Settings` > `Allow Management of Content Types` (check) > `OK`
4. Still in `Library Settings` under `Content Types` > `Add from existing site content types` tried to find the previously published content type from the content type hub (not found)

**Troubleshooting in Content Type Hub**

1. Went to `Site Settings` > `Site Collection Administration` > `Content type service application error log` (empty)
2. Went to `Site Settings` > `Site content types` > (newly created content type) > `Manage publishing for this content type` > `Publishing History` (Last successful published date: 8/9/2014 11:25:02 PM)

**Troubleshooting in Document Center**

1. Went to `Site Settings` > `Site Collection Administration` > `Content Type Publishing` > `Hubs` (Both the Taxonomy key and Content Type Hub url are correct)
2. Still in the same place under `Subscribed Content Type` (No content types have been subscribed.)

**Questions**

Have I missed something? Am I doing something wrong? What comes to the scheduler, I've waited for hours after hours.

**UPDATE**

I created a new site collection after publishing the content types and the new site collection got the content types just fine while the site collections that existed prior to creating these content types still aren't getting them.

So, I contacted the Microsoft Support as it totally seems to be bugged and got their techs looking into it. I will post an update once I got some news.

Answer (score 2):

**Resolution**

I sent a support ticket to Microsoft and after a few days of phone calls, we found a resolution. Below is the closing transcript of the issue from Microsoft:

---

**Issue Statement:**

Unable to publish Content Types through Content Type Hubs

**Scope Agreement:**

High as customer is not able to use the feature of content types on his production sites even after publishing & republishing them on the site `/sites/contentTypeHub/` for more than 48 hrs.

**Steps Taken to resolve the issue:**

We asked the backend team to resolve the issue by `refreshing the services`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go to Site Settings / Site Content Types and open your Content Type.  Select "Manage Publishing for this content type" and Publish / OK.  Then go to Site Settings / Content Type Publishing and select "Refresh all published content types on next update".  I've read that the updates happen every 4 hours.  This works for SPO.

Answer (score -1):

we need to add this content type hub to the cneteral admin--> application managemnt-->service applications-->manage service applications-->  managed meta data service-->properties

Comment: This is not available in SPO